Derivation of Dirac Hamiltonian
In Minkowski spacetime with signature $(-,\;+,\;+,\;...,\;+)$ the Dirac Lagrangian reads
$$
L=\int d^dx\;\mathcal{L}=\int d^dx\;\psi^\dagger\left(i\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-im\gamma^0\right)\psi.
$$
From it, one can proceed in two ways:

Extract the Dirac equation, and cast it into a Schrödinger-like form to identify a Hamiltonian. This is something customary in seminal works on Dirac fields in curved spacetimes. One obtains
$$
\left(\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m\right)\psi=0\\
\Rightarrow i\partial_0\psi=\left(i\gamma^0\gamma^1\partial_1-im\gamma^0\right)\psi.
$$
From here, one identifies a Hamiltonian $\boxed{h=i\gamma^0\gamma^1\partial_1-im\gamma^0}$.

Perform a Legendre transform. One obtains $$\Pi=\frac{\delta L}{\delta\partial_0\psi}=i\psi^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^0=-i\psi^\dagger.$$ Then, the Hamiltonian reads
$$
H=\int d^dx\;(-i\psi^\dagger\partial_0\psi-\mathcal{L})=\int d^dx\;\left(i\psi^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^0\partial_0\psi-i\psi^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+im\psi^\dagger\gamma^0\psi\right)\\=\int d^dx\;\psi^\dagger\left(-i\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+im\gamma^0\right)\psi.
$$
This, from the QFT perspective, can be understood as a second quantization Hamiltonian, upon anti-commutation relations being imposed on $\psi$ and $\Pi$. Therefore, one can identify a single-particle Hamiltonian, which is customarily defined as $H=\int d^dx\;\psi^\dagger h\psi$. Therefore, one finds $\boxed{h=-i\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+im\gamma^0}$.


However, these two approaches yield a different sign in the definition of the single-particle Hamiltonian $h$. I think that it is related to the fact that $\Pi=-i\psi^\dagger$, with that minus sign modifying the Hamilton equations. Furthermore, this also lead to (apparently strange) commutation relations $$\{\psi(x),\;\psi^\dagger(y)\}=-\delta(x-y).$$ However, I do not have a precise interpretation on why both approaches lead to different operators, or aboutif there is something deep going on here. I guess that a solution would be simply to define the second-quantization single-particle Hamiltonian as $H=-\int d^dx\;\psi^\dagger h\psi$, but I do not know if this is customary.

Which reference has $(\gamma^0)^2=-1$?

In the mostly-plus metric, one has $ds^2=-dt^2+d\vec{x}^2$, and so ${\gamma^0,;\gamma^0}=2\gamma^0\gamma^0=2g^{00}=-2$, so $\gamma^0\gamma^0=-1$.

Well, e.g. Srednicki uses mostly-plus metric with $(\gamma^0)^2=1$.

Yes, but that is because he modifies the Clifford algebra and defines it as ${\gamma^\mu,;\gamma^\nu}=-2\eta^{\mu\nu}$ in eq. (36.9), but I think this is not customary. E.g. Weinberg does not do that, see The Quantum Theory of Fields Vol. I, eq. 5.4.5.

Note that Weinberg does not have $i$ in the Dirac eq. (5.5.43) nor in the action (9.5.55). Although check eqs. (5.4.13) + (5.5.55).

But there isn't an $i$ factor in my action either. In my expressions, the $i$ factor arises because I expanded $\bar\psi=i\psi^\dagger\gamma^0$. This is the same definition that he uses for the adjoint, eq. 5.5.55 and 5.4.13.

There is though a difference of sign in our kinetick term. I'm checking whether this is the origin of all this problem.

@Qmechanic, I believe that that difference of sign in either the kinetick term or in the global definition of the Hamiltonian was responsible for the confusion. Thank you for your help. I have edited the question with the final conclusion.

Is anyone else bothered by the absurd physics resulting from the Dirac hamiltonian? I mean the zitterbewegung as discussed in for example Sakurai, Advanced Quantum Mechanics 3-7.

@John The problem with zitterbewegung is that according to Sakurai, Eq. 3.246, the eigenvalues of $[H_D,x] = \dot x$ are $\pm c$.

I think I will leave the question just in case it is useful for somebody. I think the whole problem arises from the definition of the action. It is easier to begin from the most customary mostly-minus (so-called West Coast) convention for the metric, $ds^2=dt^2-d\vec x^2$. Then, one changes the signature of the metric (which is the one I was interested in) to the so-called East Coast convention, $ds^2=-dt^2+d\vec x^2$. One has two choices: (a) to modify the definition of the Clifford algebra (as Srednicki does) to $\{\gamma^\mu,\;\gamma^\nu\}=-2g^{\mu\nu}$, which leaves all the expressions invariant, or (b) modify the Dirac matrices themselves, preserving the definition of Clifford algebra. This simply imply introducing a factor $\pm i$ in every gamma matrix. This modification leads to either one of the two following expressions (depending on the sign you used when introducing $\pm i$ to the gamma matrices:
$$L=-\int d^dx\;\psi^\dagger\left(i\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-im\gamma^0\right)\psi,$$
or
$$L=-\int d^dx\;\psi^\dagger\left(i\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+im\gamma^0\right)\psi.$$
As you see, there was a missing global sign in the original formulation of the question. Now, for each case, we have the same conjugate momentum $\Pi=i\psi^\dagger$, which now preserves the conventional anti-commutation relations. You can from now repeat the procedure to obtain both Hamiltonians, and you will see that everything is consistent.
